# Add Bootstrap class/style to Wordpress wp_list_pages menu items

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menuitem

I have some code that generates a sidebar menu on my Wordpress site as below...

```
<ul>
    <?php
    if($post->post_parent)
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=1");
    else
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=1");
        if ($children) { ?>
            <?php echo $children; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This outputs code in the following way...

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-94 current_page_item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, I need it to use my Bootstrap 3 styles and output the list as below...

```
<div class="list-group submenu">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Menu Item</a>
</div>
```

Basically I need to add the class of list-group-item to the a tag in the output list items. Is that at all possible?

Comment: Have a look on this answer
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130877/ways-to-give-a-wp-list-pages-menu-link-specific-class-names

Comment: You will need a `walker` for this (to customize the classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").find("li").each(function(){
      $(this).addClass("YourClass");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can your Walker Class to simply extend the output of `wp_list_pages` modify your `$output` put the Class in `functions.php`

```
class NS_CS_Walker extends Walker_page {
    function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) {
        if ( $depth ) {
            $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        } else {
            $indent = '';
        }

        extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );
        $output .= $indent . '<li><div>' . get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ) . '</div></li>';
        // modify your output here

    } // End start_el
} // End Walker Class
```

Then your rendering code should be

```
$args = array(
    'walker'      => new NS_CS_Walker()
        // your extra $args would be here
);

wp_list_pages( $args );
```

Comment: Hi there. I can't get the rendering code you've added to work. Is that based on my above example or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @lowercase add the changes in question

Comment: changed question to hopefully make more sense

Comment: as per the update, i would suggest you to use `WP_QUERY` to loop over the pages and another `wp_query` in first `WP_QUERY` to loop over the child pages then create your html in loop.